# how do i compare two lists in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code to iterate over two lists and increment a variable if there is a match, however the expected output does not match the actual output. I have attached an example test case:

I am trying to compare answer_sheet and student_answers and incrementing a variable if there is a match and returning a percentage of that value.

```py
answer_sheet: ['A', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D']
student_answers: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

- **Expecting**: 75.0
- **Actual**: 200.0

I tried iterating over the first list and second list and comparing them both and incrementing score variable if there is a match

```py
def get_test_score(answer_sheet, student_answers):
    score = 0
    for i in answer_sheet:
        for ii in student_answers:
            if i == ii:
                score += 1
    percentage = score/len(answer_sheet) * 100
    return percentage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` the two lists, then use `sum` with a generator expression to find the number of matches.

```
sum(x == y for x, y in zip(answer_sheet, student_answers)) / len(answer_sheet)
```